# JavaScript: clearInterval(); not working

Tags: javascript, html

In this program, I receive a date and time and count every second starting from the current time and date and display 'We reached" once Users date and time is reached.

But the problem is, Once that time is reached even though I clear the interval the function still keeps Executing.

I found many questions with the same title but none seems to solve my problem.

```js
function incrementCount() {
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  document.getElementById("target").innerText = "Target " + date.toString() + "  " + time.toString();
  var time = time.split(":");
  var date = date.split("-");
  var sec_t = time[2];
  var min_t = time[1];
  var hour_t = time[0];
  var day_t = date[2];
  var month_t = date[1];
  var year_t = date[0];
  var add = setInterval(
    function() {
      var today = new Date();
      var sec_c = today.getSeconds();
      var min_c = today.getMinutes();
      var hour_c = today.getHours();
      var day_c = today.getDate();
      var month_c = today.getMonth() + 1;
      var year_c = today.getFullYear();

      var display_str = "";

      //if(parseInt(year)==parseInt(year_t) && parseInt(month)==parseInt(month_t) && parseInt(day)==parseInt(day_t) && parseInt(hour) == parseInt(hour_t) && parseInt(min_t) == parseInt(time[1]) && parseInt(sec_t) == parseInt(time[2]))
      if (parseInt(year_t) == parseInt(year_c) &&
        parseInt(month_t) == parseInt(month_c) &&
        parseInt(day_t) == parseInt(day_c) &&
        parseInt(hour_t) == parseInt(hour_c) &&
        parseInt(min_t) == parseInt(min_c) &&
        parseInt(sec_t) == parseInt(sec_c)) {
        document.getElementById("current").innerText = "We Reached There";
        clearInterval(add);

      } else {
        display_str = year_c.toString() + "-" + month_c.toString() + "-" + day_c.toString() + " " + hour_c.toString() + ":" + min_c.toString() + ":" + sec_c.toString();
        document.getElementById("current").innerText = "Current " + display_str
      }

    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/2vq8w7WI0oMBuDQULT/giphy.gif">
<br><br>
<form>
  <label>Date</label>
  <input type="Date" id="date">
  <br><br>
  <label>Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="time" value="16:50:30">
</form>
<br><br>
<input type="Submit" onclick="incrementCount()">
<br><br>
<span id="target">Please select time</span>
<br><br>
<span id="current"></span>
```

Comment: What makes you think `clearInterval` is not working?  also if your checking seconds, you might want to decrease you interval from 1000, because in theory 1 second could be missed...

Comment: clearInterval() works allright in your code

Comment: When I run the problem, once the given time is reached, I'm able to see "We reached there" and in theory, it should stop (ie no more counting). But counting still continues. Could you please run the code?

Comment: Seems to work fine on chrome, I'd suggest moving the html closing tag to the end of the document as having script outside isn't valid (though most browsers will probably let you away with that)

Comment: did the program halt after showing "We Reached There" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two potential problems, `setInterval( ... ,1000)` will try to call the callback function every `1000` milliseconds, but it the delay might be larger, so you might miss a second.

But this won't explain your comment:

> When I run the problem, once the given time is reached, I'm able to see "We reached there" and in theory, it should stop (ie no more counting). But counting still continues. Could you please run the code?

This can only happen if you click `Submit` twice with different values for the input fields. Because if you click the `Submit` then an additional Interval is created but the currently running one won't be cleared, because the `add` is in the scope of `incrementCount`.

So if you click `Submit` ad realize that the time to way is either in the past or invalid, and you updated the values for the input and click `Submit` again, then you have at least one interval that won't stop counting anymore.

To solve that you need to move `add` out of the scope of `incrementCount` and call `clearInterval(add)` before you create a new interval. I move the code in a IIFE so that `add` won't pollute the global scope, and used `addEventListener`.

```js
(function() {
  var add

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    incrementCount()
  }, false)

  function incrementCount() {
    // clear old interval
    clearInterval(add)

    var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    document.getElementById("target").innerText = "Target " + date.toString() + "  " + time.toString();
    var time = time.split(":");
    var date = date.split("-");
    var sec_t = time[2];
    var min_t = time[1];
    var hour_t = time[0];
    var day_t = date[2];
    var month_t = date[1];
    var year_t = date[0];
    add = setInterval(
      function() {
        var today = new Date();
        var sec_c = today.getSeconds();
        var min_c = today.getMinutes();
        var hour_c = today.getHours();
        var day_c = today.getDate();
        var month_c = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var year_c = today.getFullYear();

        var display_str = "";

        //if(parseInt(year)==parseInt(year_t) && parseInt(month)==parseInt(month_t) && parseInt(day)==parseInt(day_t) && parseInt(hour) == parseInt(hour_t) && parseInt(min_t) == parseInt(time[1]) && parseInt(sec_t) == parseInt(time[2]))
        if (parseInt(year_t) == parseInt(year_c) &&
          parseInt(month_t) == parseInt(month_c) &&
          parseInt(day_t) == parseInt(day_c) &&
          parseInt(hour_t) == parseInt(hour_c) &&
          parseInt(min_t) == parseInt(min_c) &&
          parseInt(sec_t) == parseInt(sec_c)) {
          document.getElementById("current").innerText = "We Reached There";
          clearInterval(add);

        } else {
          display_str = year_c.toString() + "-" + month_c.toString() + "-" + day_c.toString() + " " + hour_c.toString() + ":" + min_c.toString() + ":" + sec_c.toString();
          document.getElementById("current").innerText = "Current " + display_str
        }

      }, 1000);
  }
})()
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/2vq8w7WI0oMBuDQULT/giphy.gif">
<br><br>
<form>
  <label>Date</label>
  <input type="Date" id="date">
  <br><br>
  <label>Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="time" value="16:50:30">
</form>
<br><br>
<input type="Submit" id="submit">
<br><br>
<span id="target">Please select time</span>
<br><br>
<span id="current"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, your right, the problem is caused due to multiple Submit clicks. Is there any way that I can remove the previous interval before processing the new? One way i think is to check if any interval exits(How do i do this?) and if any, to clear. Could you please help me with the code for this?

Comment: setInterval returns a value.
you can call clearInterval on it

Comment: @AlexanderTaran the OP already knows that and is using that in the code. Here it is a scoping problem. `add` is stored in the scope of `incrementCount` so it is not accessible when the button is click another time.

Comment: I ran your code. But the problem still persists. Multiple clicks will prevent the program from stopping.! or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @vikasns sorry I accientialy deleted the whole `var add =` in front of the `setInterval` instead of only removing the `var`, corrected that mistake in the sample code.

Comment: @vikasns yes I did, the code should now be `add = setInterval(`, and I in my tests it works fine.